# ios custom class Init not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am a beginner to iOS. I am trying to access/read the sqlite DB from within my App and for which I used a model class where I initialize a custom initializer. Values are getting successfully in custom initializers but my issue is that the values are not populating in modal class object.
Here is the code which I implement:

// ViewController.m

```
{
[self thehadithList];
sqlite3 *database;
NSString *databasePath;

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"hadithQudsi.db"];


if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) { 

    const char *sqlStatement = "select * from hadith";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {  


            NSInteger aID = sqlite3_column_int (compiledStatement, 0);

            NSString *aHA = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSString *aHE = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

            NSString *aRA = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
            NSString *aRE = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 4)];

            NSInteger aF = sqlite3_column_int (compiledStatement, 5);


Hadith *hadith1 = [[Hadith alloc] initWithId:aID hadith_ar:aHA hadith_en:aHE ref_ar:aRA ref_en:aRE favourites:aF];
            [thehadithList addObject:hadith1]; **// **** Here in Custom class object, values are not been getting **** //**

        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement); 

}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

// Hadith.h (this is Modal Class)

```
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger _id;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *hadith_ar;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *hadith_en;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *ref_ar;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *ref_en;
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) NSInteger  favourites;

-(id)initWithId:(NSInteger)ID hadith_ar:(NSString *)ha hadith_en:(NSString *)he ref_ar:(NSString *)ra ref_en:(NSString *)re  favourites:(NSInteger)f;
```

// Hadith.m

```
@synthesize _id,hadith_ar,hadith_en,ref_ar,ref_en,favourites;

-(id)initWithId:(NSInteger)ID hadith_ar:(NSString *)ha hadith_en:(NSString *)he ref_ar:(NSString *)ra ref_en:(NSString *)re  favourites:(NSInteger )f
{

if (self =  [super init]) {

    self._id = ID;
    self.hadith_ar = ha;
    self.hadith_en = he;

    self.ref_ar = ra;
    self.ref_en = re;
    self.favourites = f;
}



return self;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Is there anything missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    -(id)initWithId:(NSInteger)ID hadith_ar:(NSString *)ha hadith_en:(NSString *)he ref_ar:(NSString *)ra ref_en:(NSString *)re  favourites:(NSInteger )f
    {

    self =  [super init];
        self._id = ID;
        self.hadith_ar = ha;
        self.hadith_en = he;

        self.ref_ar = ra;
        self.ref_en = re;
        self.favourites = f;




return self;
}
```

Comment: Not even a single error is getting, everything looks fine but values are not getting in class object

Comment: thanks for help but it's did not working with updated code

Comment: are yo u calling initializer via [alloc init] ?

Comment: Yes i'm doing the same, calling initializer in ViewController.m

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
-(id)initWithId:(NSInteger)ID hadith_ar:(NSString *)ha hadith_en:(NSString *)he ref_ar:(NSString *)ra ref_en:(NSString *)re  favourites:(NSInteger )f
        {
        self =  [super init];
            __id = ID;
            _hadith_ar = ha;
            _hadith_en = he;
            _ref_ar = ra;
            _ref_en = re;
            _favourites = f;
    return self;
    }
```

Comment: Try to remove @synthesize, and execute with this

    `-(instancetype)initWithId:(NSInteger)ID hadith_ar:(NSString *)ha hadith_en:(NSString *)he ref_ar:(NSString *)ra ref_en:(NSString *)re  favourites:(NSInteger )f
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        __id = ID;
        _hadith_ar = ha;
        _hadith_en = he;
        _ref_ar = ra;
        _ref_en = re;
        _favourites = f;
    }
    return self;
}`

Comment: Emm..What is this:

`[self thehadithList];` ?

And, in which part of life cycle you execute this code?

Comment: try to put breakpoint in the last `return self` in model init method
And make sure what values it have, if all is ok, then look problem in other place.
I spotted this one `[thehadithList addObject:hadith1]`
If you use it, it must be an NSMutableArray,  and you must write its own getter by yourself. Otherwise you will get empty array.